# How to quit iPhoto in the middle of importing photos

Tags: iphone, photos.app, import

I plugged my iPhone into my Mac and it started importing photos from iPhone. It's been two days and I need to shut down my Mac. How do I stop importing the photos?

Comment: 2 days sounds like an awfully long time for this process. Are photos actually being imported, or is the process frozen? Just restart the Mac with the phone connected, or just unplug the phone and restart the computer. You won't damage anything.

Comment: If you eject the iPhone, the importing will stop and continue the next time you connect the iPhone. Anyway, I totally agree with @IconDaemon.

Answer (score 1):

On Spotlight search start typing "Activity Monitor", click on it. The on activity monitor find Photos, click on it once, then at the top left you will see an X icon, click on it and choose force quit..